# Pivot table data retrieval

Tags: excel, google-sheets, offset

I know this is easy, just need a quick answer. I have a Pivot table that has three columns and about 1k rows.  I need to get 1 number out of the list per agent. for example:

[Example pic of the pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhzDq.png)

^^the highlighted number is the number i need to return

What I've come up with is this:
    `=if(and('Calls Handled Pivot'!A1='Agent Breakdown'!A$3,'Calls Handled Pivot'!B1="wrap-up"),'Calls Handled Pivot'!C1, "")`

So, If ColumnA = the agent's name AND columnB = "wrap-up" THEN give me the number in columnC, otherwise leave the cell blank.

Then i run that formula all the way down another sheet until it picks up the number. in the adjacent column i run the formula down all the rows AGAIN for the next agent until it picks up the number i want. after all of that, i just do the sum of all columns on that sheet to get the numbers all in row 1. the problem is with the amount of data running through this, it's basically crashing the page when it tries to run all those formulas.

I'm open to any ideas but i did have this thought-process: is there a way to run that formula so that instead of leaving the cell blank, it will just search down the next row until the number is found?

That or.. some kind of vlookup that verifies two values, like columnA = agents name AND columnB = "wrap-up"

Comment: You should look into query. Try something like `=QUERY(A:C, "Select * where B = 'Wrap-up' ")`. If you're looking for a specific agent, try `=QUERY(A:C, "Select * where A = 'name goes here' and B = 'Wrap-up' ")`.  https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage

Comment: Excel and Google Sheets have not the same features for pivot tables. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 0):

For the quick non automated method here is what I would do (Assuming D&E are blank columns)
Formula in column D :

`"=IF(B2="Wrap-up",A2,"")`

Column E

`=IF(B2="Wrap-up",C2,"")`

Select column D&E and paste them into a new tab. Remove duplicates (to get rid of most blanks). Then delete the singular blank line left.

---

Automated version

On one tab have a list of unique Agent Names. 
On the next column fill in:

`=GETPIVOTDATA("Total",PivotSheetNameHere!$A$1,"Agent Name", A1)`

Reference:
https://www.contextures.com/xlPivot06.html